# microtype versus mathastext: unknown slot number error

Tags: fonts, microtype

The following MWE compiles with `pdftex` but produces a mysterious warning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Here is some text
\end{document}
```

The warning is:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\%'
(microtype)                in font encoding `OT1' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `default'.
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the compiled document, but I get dozens of this error in the full doc and I was wondering what it meant...

Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` doesn't help (except the error is now about T1 encoding instead. Permuting the order of the packages doesn't seem to help either.

A `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
libertine.sty    2009/05/22a - 4.5.1a -LaTeX: Font libertine - (License GPL) Michael Niedermair
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
  xspace.sty    2006/05/08 v1.12 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
     fxl.inc
     fxb.inc
microtype.sty    2009/03/27 v2.3d Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)
microtype.cfg    2009/03/27 v2.3d microtype main configuration file (RS)
mathastext.sty    2011/02/07 1.12 Use the text font in simple mathematics
   t1fxl.fd    2009/05/22 scaled font definitions for libertine T1/fxl (Nm).
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Like I said, this error doesn't seem to translate into anything *wrong* with the output PDF, but I'd like to know what's going on. (I'm trying to get rid of the clutter from my log file...

I've learned that the `silence` package can hide these errors, but I'd like to know what's causing it. It seems that it's not a conflict with that particular font, since it also works if you substitute other fonts for `libertine`.

Can anyone confirm that they get this error?

Comment: the current (1.15g) version of `mathastext` on CTAN has corrected this issue of compatibility with `microtype`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (to me) mysterious reasons, **mathastext** redefines `\%` to respect `\mathbf` or `\mathit` in math mode:

```
\renewcommand{\%}{\ifmmode\mt@mmode@percent\else\char37\relax\fi}
```

where `\mt@mmode@percent` means `\mathchar"7425`. It does the same for `\#`, `\$` and `\&`, but it seems that only `\%` is considered by **microtype** for its protrusion tables and this definition confuses it. Doing

```
\chardef\%=37
```

after loading **mathastext** (so as to restore the original definition) avoids the warning. Of course

```
\let\originalpercent\%
\usepackage{mathastext}
\let\%\originalpercent
```

is exactly the same.

`\mathchar"7425` means:

- normally use character 0x25 (hexadecimal, decimal 37) from math family 4, which is the normal math font, ad defined by **mathastext** (the number may actually change, but it always refers to the basic font);
- however, if `\mathgroup` is greater than -1 (that is we are in `\mathbf` or `\mathit` or another of such kind of commands), use character 0x25 from family `\mathgroup`.

With the restored definition, `\%` in math mode will use the font from math family 0, which is always the text font, so it *may* be different from the basic math font.

Comment: This interaction with microtype can be avoided through loading `mathastext` with option `nospecials`: this turns off the mathastextification of the \%, \#, \$, and \& characters. But Enrico's proposed workarounds suffice as apparently only \% initiated a problem.

Comment: the redefinitions of `\%` and the like were a bit strange, but actually modeled on `\$`. The `1.15g` version of `mathastext` has corrected this problem of incompatibility with `microtype`. Regarding the mathcode's, it is primarily to change the math font family. Additionally the 7 will as you explain make the characters sensitive to math alphabet commands, which may or may not be a useful thing. The problem is that to be consistent `mathastext` should do that also for things such as `!` or `;` but it can't because these characters have an assigned type (`\mathclose`, `\mathpunct`).